# "hiding" warning. What does it mean in this case?

Tags: java, generics, warnings, subclass

I began making a class and there was a warning with the generic type "T" in the subclass.

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    public class SomeInnerClass<T> {

    }
}
```

What is the following code warning be about exactly? Will it make any difference at all if I change the generic of the subclass to another letter?

Comment: the type parameter of inner class is hiding type parameter of top level class. try different type parameter such as `public class SomeInnerClass<V extends T>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to defining a class inside the class, the warning is about the inner class hiding the parameter `T` from Outer Class.